# How to create Teams Message via REST from an Application properly

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a c# service, the service is running somewhere in the azure cloud without an user interface. some specific events should trigger new messages to a team channel.

According to this documentation, the Create Message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http is only supported by delegated account, not by the application tokens.

How can i create a delegated token for my service application without specific user account and without a login interface in the cloud?
Which Authentication Provider is the right one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question : [chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , supports only the **Delegated Permission type.**

**What exactly is Delegated Permission Type?**
A permission which specify scope-based access using delegated authorization from the signed-in.
The reason on the emphasis of the above point is being that - for Delegated permission we would need the context of a **user account**

Coming back to your questions :

***How can i create a delegated token for my service application without specific user account***

You can obtain a token without a specific user account but this will not help your cause.In order to overcome this, I would suggest a creation of service account - this account has permission over the teams.Part 2 of this questions suggests which provider can help without the login prompt.

The steps include :

- Register your app.
- Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph on your app.
- Get administrator consent.
- Get an access token.
- Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

Detailing of the steps is included in the article here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

***without a login interface in the cloud***

Now you could use the below option :

[image]
[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials](http://Microsoft%20identity%20platform%20and%20OAuth%202.0%20Resource%20Owner%20Password%20Credentials)

In this provider, you will be passing the creds of the service account.

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<YOUR CLIENT ID>
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=<YOUR USERNAME>
&password=<YOUR PASSWORD>
&grant_type=password
```

You can generate the token for your service account by above request and application can consume the chatMessage API.